# Measuring a real object with two static calibrated cameras

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, triangulation, stereo-3d

**The goal**. To estimate the 3D location (x, y, z) of the centre, the width (larger diameter of the glass) and height of the glass. Similarly as in [this drawing](https://i.postimg.cc/RhBGNdyZ/goal.png). The inputs are two images, one coming from one different camera ([here](https://i.postimg.cc/g2PRp1vQ/Picture1-png-1.png) and [here](https://i.postimg.cc/250B46PN/Picture1-png-2.png)).

**The setup**. The images come from two fixed and calibrated (known intrinsic and extrinsic parameters) cameras.

**My attempt**.

1. I have segmented the image using FCN or DeepLab. Results [here](https://i.postimg.cc/VNfCrMZF/Picture1-png-3.png) and [here](https://i.postimg.cc/VkBtk4g6/Picture1-png-4.png).
2. Then I have got a binary mask of the class of interest (glass) and extracted the most left, up, right and bottom parts of that mask. Results [here](https://i.postimg.cc/kGHr0kDp/Picture1-png-1.png) and [here](https://i.postimg.cc/G3g1Tszx/Picture1-png-2.png).
3. I have obtained four 3D points trough triangulation of the "corresponding points" (upper of image 1 with the upper of image 2, most right of image 1 with the most right of image 2, etc...).
4. I compute the dimensions as: width = | left - right |, and height = |up - bottom|.

**Issues**. The points are not actual correspondences, therefore the reprojection is inaccurate and then the measure is inaccurate as well (resulting on up to 3cm error). Note that if I choose manually the corresponding pixels on both images and then triangulate I get approximatively 0.1cm error.

**Can you guide me on how better (more accurately) solve this problem?**

Thank you!

PS: I am using python and OpenCV.

Comment: are your computed correspondences on the epilines or could this be an improvememt?

Comment: Currently, I am doing nothing regarding epipolar lines. Do you mean that I should get one point on image 1, draw the epipolar line to image 2 and try to find the correspondence there?
Could you please elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: yes, you said that choosing correspondences manually will give good results. Since the correspondences must be present on the epilines, maybe you could improve your correspondences by limiting the search to the epiline. But I'm not an expert in stereo/3d reconstruction

Comment: Hi Micka, I have tried this but it does not work well. The calibration board is on the plane of the table. Therefore, when I draw the epipolar line of a point that is not in that plane the line is completely wrong (wrt to the plane where the point was selected, e.g. on the top of the glass). I do not think I can follow this approach...
Does anyone have further ideas!?
Thank you!

Comment: I have also tried with RealSense cameras (depth camera) but the depth is not helping on the objects I want to measure as they are mostly transparent and the depth is not working well...

Does anyone have any idea how to tackle this problem :) ? (thank you!).